# AWS CloudFront err_too_many_redirects

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I'm using S3 to host my static website (it's an Angular page) and Route 53 to be able to use the domain I have. (I bought the domain at Hostgator). Whenever I say and use here 'example.com', be aware that is the same name of the domain I bought. In the S3 I have to buckets. Let's call them www.example.com and example.com. The example.com holds the application itself and it's set up as a static website hosting. It also has public permission with the proper Bucket Policy. The www.example.com is a just a redirect bucket, which is set up as a static website hosting to just redirect requests. In this bucket, the 'target bucket or domain' is the 'example.com' bucket.

In Route 53, I have a hosted zone with the name 'example.com'. There, I have 4 record sets. Two for setting up the domain I bought to be used at AWS. It's an 'NS - Name server' and an 'SOA - Start of authority'. They are properly configured to host my domain name. The other two are 'A - IPv4 address', one with the name of 'example.com' and the other with the name of 'www.example.com'. In these two cases, the Alias target is my 'example.com' bucket in S3.

So far I was following the docs and it works well. I can load my domain at the browser typing 'example.com' or typing 'www.example.com', which redirects to 'example.com' and load my application. So far, so good. The application was working, but of course without an SSL certificate.

Then I created a Distribution at CloudFront to use my SSL certificate. In the distribution, I set the Origin as the endpoint of my 'www.example.com' bucket at S3. The CNAMEs property I set as www.example.com, example.com. I used my SSL certificate and all works fine to deploy the distribution. So far so good...

At AWS S3, in the www.example.com bucket, in the protocol of the redirect requests, I set it to 'https', as the docs said.

Then, in Route 53, I set the Alias Target of the two 'A - IPv4 address' record sets, mentioned earlier, with the CloudFront distribution I created.

That's it. It was supposed to be done, but always when I go to 'example.com' with the browser, I get this error:

'err_too_many_redirects'

The interesting thing is that the URL became secure, with the https and the green padlock. But the application doesn't load. The redirect from the www.example.com to example.com still works.

Docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/tutorial-redirecting-dns-queries.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/migrate-dns-domain-inactive.html#migrate-dns-get-zone-file-domain-inactive

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *In the distribution, I set the Origin as the endpoint of my 'www.example.com' bucket at S3.*

You have pointed the CloudFront distribution to the wrong bucket.  This is the first problem.  You are pointing everything to the bucket that always redirects every request.

> *The CNAMEs property I set as www.example.com, example.com.*

You have two buckets but only one CloudFront distribution.  This is the second problem.  You need two CloudFront distributions, one to handle example.com and the other to handle www.example.com.  Each one has only one Alternate Domain Name ("CNAME") value and points to the matching bucket.

Comment: Just wondering: I also have a node.js server running at Elastic Beanstalk. Would be possible to config it to be 'example.com/api' ???

Comment: Or would be better to use 'api.example.com'? Whats better?

Comment: @Anderson In the example.com distribution, create a new Origin pointing to your beanstalk URL and then create two new Cache Behaviors -- one matching path pattern `/api` and one matching `/api/*` -- and configure those new cache behaviors to use the new origin you just created.

Comment: Note also that when beanstalk receives the request, the *entire* path requested by the client will pass through, so `/api/foo` will be seen by beanstalk as `/api/foo` and not just `/foo`.  Assuming that the path pattern will be removed from the request is a common mistake some people make.  It's possible to modify the path CloudFront passes through to the backend using a Lambda@Edge Origin Request trigger, but that's usually an unnecessary exercise unless you're passing requests through to a system that can't be modified.

Comment: "You have two buckets but only one CloudFront distribution. This is the second problem. You need two CloudFront distributions, one to handle example.com and the other to handle www.example.com" Well, the Amazon CloudFront documentation explicitly tells you to use the same CloudFront distribution for both the subdomain and the root domain. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-cloudfront-walkthrough.html#update-record-sets

Comment: @JereKäpyaho that's the S3 documentation, not the CloudFront documentation, and it's a poorly-designed example of a setup you would not typically use in the real world.  You would only follow these steps if you wanted both example.com and www.example.com to serve the same content, and didn't want one to redirect to the other.

Comment: Thanks for responding, and sorry I mislabeled the documentation; still, that is the guidance the AWS docs give. Oddly, I have used that setup for several websites with no problems, but recently one of them started giving the "too many redirects" error. I seem to have solved it by deleting "www" subdomain from the CloudFront distribution and also removed the CNAME record from Route53. I never used the subdomain in any communication anyway, so it's not a big deal if it errors out. Some may want that kind of setup, though.